# Wrapped ObservableCollection<T> throwing `'EditItem' is not allowed for this view` when bound to a WPF DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid, observablecollection

I created a wrapper to extend an `ObservableCollection<T>`

```
[Serializable]
public abstract class ModelCollection<TModel> : ModelCollectionBase,
    IList<TModel>, INotifyCollectionChanged, INotifyPropertyChanged
    where TModel : ModelBase<TModel>
{
    private ObservableCollection<TModel> wrappedCollection = new ObservableCollection<TModel>();

    // wrapper implementation goes here
}
```

I thought it was working fine until I attempted to bind items from a list to a DataGrid.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding /Orders}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Order Id" Binding="{Binding OrderId}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Date Time" Width="125" Binding="{Binding DateTime}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Notes" Width="125" Binding="{Binding Notes}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Cost" Width="75" Binding="{Binding Cost}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

The items appear in the grid, but double clicking a cell throws `'EditItem' is not allowed for this view.`

The exception isn't thrown when I replace my `ModelCollection<TModel>` with a regular `ObservableCollection<T>`.

My intent is to allow editing on the cells. Am I missing an interface on my wrapper?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to fix this by explicitly implementing `IList`

```
[Serializable]
public abstract class ModelCollection<TModel> : ModelCollectionBase,
    IList<TModel>, IList, INotifyCollectionChanged, INotifyPropertyChanged
    where TModel : ModelBase<TModel>
{
    private ObservableCollection<TModel> wrappedCollection = new ObservableCollection<TModel>();

    // wrapper implementation goes here
}
```